# Transport V.S c# forms project from pc to another

Tags: sql, copy, hashtag

can i make a copy for my C# forms Application to other pc's
P.S: the form is connected to a database.
if we name **PC(A) sender** and **PC(B) receiver**
if PC(B) doesn't have visual studio neither sql servel management studio could the project work in PC(B) or should i download (V.S-SSMS) in PC(B) to run the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just copy the files from `bin\Release` folder to that another PC B with Windows and appropriate [.NET Framework version](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/framework) installed.

If you need the PC B to run its own database server, you will have to install there [SQL LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb) or another required [edition of SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). Or you can also change db connection string on PC B to point to PC A's SQL Server database if you have it installed there and you have enabled access to it on Windows firewall.